# How to implement a custom Partitioner<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, partitioning, plinq, partitioner

I am trying to understand how to implement `Partitioner<T>`.

My case:

We read from a file and we insert to the Azure table storage. We use tasks in order to speed up the process. The file has nearly 10,000,000 lines.

I tried to implement a more elegant solution using Parallel execution and partitioning. I would like to partition this large group of 9,000,000 into  a group of partition sets and distribute them in 30-50 threads.

I would think that I need a dynamic implementation of `Partitioner<List<List<TableEntity>>>`. I have few examples, the one with the StringPartitioner, but it's not really helpful for my case as I need an IEnumerator for `List<List<TableEntity>>`.

If all this is confusing, please let me know so I can clarify.

The problem is how to implement a dynamic Partitioner in `List<List<TableEntity>>`.

Comment: Please have a loot at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997416(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why do you think you need a custom partitioner? How exactly are the entities supposed to be processed? (Is each `TableEntity` independent, or do you need to process a whole `List<TableEntity>` at once?)